# automaically Checked a checkbox when a row is being select

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want a function that, if I click on a column for edit, the full row will be selected and also I want a invisible checkbox for marking if the row is being selected, so basically if I click on the editable column the corresponding checkbox will the checked. I want this function for update all the edited rows by click on single update button.

here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
 table: '#data_table',
 idSrc:  'id',
 fields: [

     {name: 'id' },
     {name: 'company_name' },
     {name: 'status'  },
     {name: 'created_at' },
     {name: 'updated_at'  }
     // etc
 ]
} );
$('#data_table').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child, :nth-child(2), :nth-child(5), :nth-child(6))', function () {

 editor.inline( this);
  // select: true;
 } );
client_table = $('#data_table').DataTable( {
 // dom: "Bfrtip",
 columns: [
     { data: 'multi_id' },
     { data: 'id' },
     { data: 'company_name' , className: 'editable'},
     { data: 'status' , className: 'editable'},
     { data: 'created_at' },
     { data: 'updated_at' }

 ],

 select: {
    style: 'multi'
 }
 } );

} );`
```

can anyone help me here, how I can edit this code for this? and thank u.

Comment: I see no PHP, looks like jquery to me.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you submit the edited data via ajax as soon as editing is finished? thats what datatable inline editor is made for..

take a look here: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

for the serverside part to safe the data!

Comment: may be in this case data is being updated when I just edit a single column, but I don't want to work like this, I want to edit the columns or rows, and finally I'll click a submit button to update all the edited data i database. correct me if I am wrong in anywhere.